# Qt quick ApplicationWindow 'color' for background color doesn't work

Tags: qt, background-color, applicationwindow

I created a simple Qt quick application with a single main.qml, which is like the code below. The problem is the background color of window wasn't set to `#ffffff`, instead it's set to light gray (the default color of window on Windows I thought). The rectangle's color is set correctly.

I'm using Qt Creator 3.3.1 (opensource) based on Qt 5.4.1 on windows.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello")
    width: 200
    height: 200
    visible: true
    color: "#FFFFFF"

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "#ffffff"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ApplicationWindowStyle` QML Type provide styling for `ApplicationWindow`. Default 
`ApplicationWindowStyle` represent background as:

```
background: Rectangle {
        visible: !styleData.hasColor
        color: SystemPaletteSingleton.window(true)
}
```

`styleData.hasColor` property is defined as:

```
property QtObject styleData: QtObject {
    readonly property bool hasColor: window.color != "#ffffff"
}
```

So, if your `ApplicationWindow` color is `#FFFFFF`, you see light gray rectangle over window background.

To make white background, you need to set custom `ApplicationWindowStyle`.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    style: ApplicationWindowStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works. BTW, any suggestion where I could find this sort of details on Qt doc website or others. I did some searching before asking this question, but didn't find anything helpful. I'm new to Qt :) thanks.

Comment: @zhangwt You can look at Qt source code on [gitorious](https://qt.gitorious.org/).

Comment: Is it normal for Qt Designer to not recognise these properties? The text editor keeps marking 'style' as an invalid property name, and the QMLJS designer will no longer display the layout. However, when I compile it, it works fine.

Comment: @Daniel Saner [http://stackoverflow.com/q/28899984/2792656](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28899984/2792656)

Comment: @DanielSaner Using "import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4" solved the unrecognize property issue for me (previously I was using 1.2).