# qt: invalid property name 'x' (M16) for button

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using Qt 5.4.1 in QtCreator 3.3.1

I've imported QtQuick.Controls 1.2 into my QML and added a series of buttons:

```
Rectangle {
    id: buttonBar
    x: 480
    y: 0
    width: 320
    height: 80
    Button {
        x: 0
        y: 0

        width: 80
        height: 60

        text: "Songs"
    }

    Button {
        x: 80
        y: 0

        width: 80
        height: 60

        text: "Artists"
    }

    Button {
        x: 160
        y: 0

        width: 80
        height: 60

        text: "Albums"
    }

    Button {
        x: 240
        y: 0

        width: 80
        height: 60

        text: "Back"
    }
}
```

They all render fine when I run the program, but everytime that QtCreator opens the qml file it jumps into design mode and I get the warning:

```
invalid property name 'x' (M16)
```

and the lines where I use x, y, width and height are all underlined when I view the file in edit mode.

But the documentation says these are valid properties for my buttons - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button-members.html

How do I stop/resolve this error message?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a bug in the type info that is generated for controls for use of Qt Creator.

To suppress this error, add comment:

```
Button {
    // @disable-check M16
    x: 80
    y: 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This suppresses the error, but still doesn't allow the button to be positioned or edited using the handy Designer mode. Any tricks to get a button working in Designer mode?

Comment: @halfnibble Only change your Qt to version without bug. Qt 5.4.0 and QtCreator 3.3.0 is fine.

Comment: We can fix the problem here with the solution but the problem is that the autocomplete feature is not working well.

Answer (score 8):

Try to add import QtQuick.Window 2.2 before all other imports in qml.

Comment: This one is really useful

Comment: For me it's `import QtQml.Models 2.2` on top to fix this. The order of imports matters here.

Answer (score 5):

I moved these imports to the top, before any other import and problem got resovled:

```
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtQml 2.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It solved my issue but do you know why the problem appears and why these imports will solve it?